# Как корректно указать путь к изображению PyQT

Tags: python, pyqt5, path

Решил перейти с *Tkinter* на *PyQT*, набросал интерфейс и возникла проблема с рамками и фонами для `label`'ов. К примеру у меня в коде есть строка:

```
self.label.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/image/fone_and_border_v2.png);")
```

Создавая папку внутри проекта (как я полагаю путь начинается с корня каталога) под названием **`image`** и помещая внутрь нее файл с изображением, название которого идентично тому, что указан в коде.

Изображение при запуске не отображается. Я предполагаю, что его нужно указывать иначе. 
Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: А вам нужен именно `border-image`? Может такой вариант вам нужен `"background-image: url(image.png)";`?

Comment: В идеале и тот и тот вариант, потому что имеется и рамка и бэкграунд

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c **`:/`** указываются файлы, находящиеся в файле ресурсов https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html

Если нужен локальный файл вне ресурсов, так и указывайте

```
self.label.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(image/fone_and_border_v2.png);")
```

или

```
self.label.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(./image/fone_and_border_v2.png);")
```

Comment: Благодарю за информацию